# NW.JS / node-webkit : Where is SQlite DB stored

Tags: node-webkit, nw.js

I am using NW.JS, formerly known as node-webkit, to compile desktop app on windows but for the life of me, I can't figure out where the SQLite DB is stored.

If the page in NW.JS is using SQLite, does anyone know where it is stored?

Comment: What is the SQLite path you're giving and what is the applications designated workspace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything created during the course of a NW program running is written to:

> C:\Users\YOUR-USER-NAME\AppData\Local\YOUR-APP-NAME\

And...

> C:\Users\YOUR-USER-NAME\AppData\Local\Temp\nw1740_11663\

NB: The "nw1740_11663" is a randomly generated number for each session and is only accessible while the app is running because the directory gets deleted upon program exit.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for.. Thanks!